# What is the geometric description of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have been studying transformations and came across a question which stumped me.
What is the geometric description of the following matrix:
$$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
2 & 2\\ 
2 & 2
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$
Does this describe a 2 way shear and scale, the transformation of a line or am I way off?

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is real and symmetric, which means it has a full set of real eigenvalues with orthogonal eigenvectors: that means that geometrically the matrix represents a nonuniform scaling about an orthogonal set of axes.

In particular the eigenvectors are

- $(1,1)$ with eigenvalue $4$;
- $(1,-1)$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Therefore the matrix represents scaling by $4$ in the direction of the axis $y=x$ and scaling by $0$ in the direction of the axis $y=-x$.

Comment: I'd just like to add that in general the action of a 2-by-2 real matrix can be visualized easily using the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition).

Comment: @derpy Yes, that's a great point.

Comment: How do you know it is scaling and not say a reflection?

Comment: what would the geometric of $$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-2 & 3\\ 
-3 & 4
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$ be then?

Comment: @jakewalsh if it were a reflection, one of the eigenvalues would be negative.

Comment: Yeah so I understand that since a negative scale is a reflection but the eigen vector for the other matrix is $$ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $$ With eigenvalue 1 but when I draw the transformation on a unit square it is not a scale along y=x with scale factor 1, why?

Comment: @jakewalsh Your second matrix is not symmetric. Therefore it will not correspond to just a scaling---there will be a rotation as well. You can compute this rotation by doing an SVD, as suggested by derpy.

Comment: This came up on my a level question sheet and we haven't done eigenvectors yet so i'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @jakewalsh You can test what the matrix does to some set of basis vectors, of course.

Comment: Ive done that and so far I see the line y=x is an invariant line but i can't seem to find a transformation for the other points.

Comment: @jakewalsh I don't know what to tell you... there is nothing to "find", you simply notice that $A(\alpha e_1 + \beta e_2) = \alpha Ae_1 + \beta Ae_2$ and you have a complete description of how $A$ acts on any point in the plane. In any case, these comments are not the place for extended discussion---if you have a new question about a different matrix, or want to ask how to solve the problem using a specific different technique, you should make a new post.